# Parsing Mixed XML and HTML with php

Tags: php, json, xml

I am doing a curl request and getting the following back:

```
//....curl stuff....//
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
print_R($result);


     <html><body onload="if (parent.submitterLoaded) 
parent.submitterLoaded();">{"AuthenticationType":0, 
"DateDisplayFormat":1, "SystemURL":"https://rmm.server.com", 
"Username”:”user”, "UserID":"12205_1", "Error":"", "Success":true, 
"ClientID":1, "SessionGuid":"9eb91231b04-feca-4704-b445-
cc5b369581e3", "tag":"", "LastRequestDateTime":"636421428277379996"}
 </body></html><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body>
<LoginResponse xmlns="http://Iris.net" /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I have tried xml_parser_create and

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

and i get a garbled mess in return.

```
Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : XML 
declaration allowed only at the start of the document in 
/var/www/cron/billing/test.php on line 68
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): b6-bd4dd8a0760b", 
"LastRequestDateTime":"636421426011959977"}</body></html><?xml in 
/var/www/cron/billing/test.php on line 68
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string():                                                                                
^ in /var/www/cron/billing/test.php on line 68
```

I can see what appears to be some json at the {"Keys" area of the response.  How can i parse this correctly?

What other info do you need to help answer question?

Comment: What is that even supposed to be read by? That's not valid XML, nor valid HTML.
You could split it at `</html>` to separate the XML from the HTML and use different parsers for the two, then read the HTML body to get the JSON inside, but it's a mess.

Comment: yea i know it looks like garbage, but thats the response i am getting... I will try what you said. thanks

Comment: I'll try anything. thats a lot less hacky then explode("<",$......);

Comment: any idea what the server devs were smoking? must have been some hard stuff. this is html, json, and XML Soap all mixed together

Comment: You should see their api docs...my 6 year old could give more details.....

Answer (score 1):

The first warning indicate the parser doesn't like the second part `<?xml version..`. So get rid of it:

```
$result = substr($result, 0, strpos($result, '<?xml version'));
```

Then to pull out the JSON string, use:

```
$jsonString = (string) simplexml_load_string($result)->body;
$array = json_decode($jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

extract the json with DOMDocument, and parse it with json_decode

```
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($response);
$json_data=json_decode(trim($domd->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0)->textContent));
```

now the stuff in the json can be accessed like `$UserID=$json_data->UserID;`, ... and the stuff in the HTML can be accessed in $domd,  like `$loginResponse=$domd->getElementsByTagName("LoginResponse")->item(0)->textContent;` - didn't see anything useful in the html other than the json, though..